# Got Outlook message saying something about redirect to asusnetwork.net

Tags: trojan

Possible trojan? I got message from Outlook dialog asking if I want redirect to asusnetwork.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asusnetwork.net` is a domain name programmed into Asus routers referring to itself (the router).

It's so you can use it to get at your router's web interface regardless of it's current LAN IP.

Not sure why Outlook said anything about it, but it was probably just network route or name lookup confusion some place along the way. Regardless, it's nothing to worry about if you have an Asus router, and it's not happening all the time.

More info [here](http://support.asus.com/Search/KDetail.aspx?SLanguage=en&no=8E02838F-4F1D-0310-EE1C-5575D6C309C6&t=2) and [here](http://forums.smallnetbuilder.com/showthread.php?t=9089)

Comment: It is something to worry about. See my answer on [this related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91741/asus-rt-ac68-login-page-is-redirecting-to-some-amazonaws-page).